# How to strome image in Android Database from imageView

Tags: android

First off all i am the beginner to android.If i make some mistake so sorry for that.

So now I want to store the image in android database which take  this image from the image view.the image will hold by the `ImageView` which is taken by camera.
the database class is:

```
public class DatabaseOperation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "PASS";
    public static final String COL_4 = "CONTACT";
    public static final String COL_5 = "NIC";
    public static final String COL_6= "CONFIRM";
      public static final String IMAGE_KEY="IMAGE";

    public DatabaseOperation (Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,PASS TEXT,CONFIRM TEXT,NIC INTEGER,CONTACT INTEGER,IMAGE_KEY BLOB)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public  boolean insertData(String name,String pass,String confrim,String contact,String nic,byte[]image)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_2,name);
        cv.put(COL_3,pass);
        cv.put(COL_6,confrim);
        cv.put(COL_4,contact);
        cv.put(COL_5,nic);
        cv.put(IMAGE_KEY,image);
       long result= db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        if(result==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to store the image which is in the imageview by clicking the register button.

[image]

in this screenshot, this image which is lock is in the `ImageView` i want to store this image in database by click the register button

and this is the activity class
now i don't know how to use this in activity class is:

```
public void reg(View v) {

    if(!(pass.getText().toString().equals(confirm.getText().toString()))) {
        showMessage("Error!","Password not matched");
        pass.setText("");
        confirm.setText("");
    } else {
        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(name.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString(),
        confirm.getText().toString(), cont.getText().toString(), nic.getText().toString());

        if (isInserted == true)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration Succes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Record     Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Which is your imageview?

Comment: for example if i want to store image from the imageview.click on this scren shot sentence will show you snapshot

Answer (score 0):

you can store image in sqlite database with type BLOB,here is the sample db code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";

    // Table Names
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "table_image";

    // column names
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "image_name";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image_data";

    // Table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + "("+ 
                       KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + 
                       KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);

        // create new table
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Insert in the Database:

```
public void addEntry( String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException{
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME,    name);
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
    database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
}
```

Retrieving data:

```
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);
```

you must convert your bitmap to byte[] before you insert it in your db

Comment: and how to use in activity class in my case i mean in my code:

Comment: you have not added you image parameter in the function myDb.insertData(name.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString(),
                            confirm.getText().toString(), cont.getText().toString(), nic.getText().toString());

Comment: so what type of parameter i should to pass,string,byte etc.as i told i am the beginner

Comment: if you don't mind please edit my code and pass the perameter which one which is require in activity class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your image to a byte array and then pass it into your `insertData` method. The image you can get it from an imageview (assuming its the lock icon you would like to save) or directly from your resources.

Try this,

```
    // get image from ImageView
    // imageView is your your ImageView
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
    //Create a new buffer
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
    //Move the byte data to the buffer
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

    // Image as byte array
    byte[] array = buffer.array();

    // your insert code
    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(
        name.getText().toString(), 
        pass.getText().toString(),
        confirm.getText().toString(), 
        cont.getText().toString(), 
        nic.getText().toString(),
        array
    );
```